# Glob files and sort by filemtime and into months

Tags: php, glob

Yes, I know this is ugly code :) And it doesn't work.

I'm globbing all the .php files in a directory and then sorting them by file timestamp, and then I want to echo the file names into each month. But how do I fix this loop so the echoed output of each month is correct? The files by $path are sorted by date, but the $link_title is the same for all files in all months, so I don't see that the $paths are getting arranged by month.

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {

        $files[$path] = filemtime($path);

} arsort($files);

$currentdate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

$julybegin = strtotime("2018-07-01 00:00:00");
$julyend = strtotime("2018-07-31 23:23:59");

$junebegin = strtotime("2018-06-01 00:00:00");
$juneend = strtotime("2018-06-30 23:23:59");

$maybegin = strtotime("2018-05-01 00:00:00");
$mayend = strtotime("2018-05-31 23:23:59");

$aprilbegin = strtotime("2018-04-01 00:00:00");
$aprilend = strtotime("2018-04-30 23:23:59");

$timestamp = filemtime ($path);
$link_title = $path;

    foreach ($files as $path => $timestamp) {

if($timestamp > $julybegin && $timestamp < $julyend) {
echo '<li>';
echo $path . ' ' . $link_title;
echo '</li>';

} else {

if($timestamp > $junebegin && $timestamp < $juneend) {
echo '<li>';
echo $path . ' ' . $link_title;
echo '</li>';

} else {

if (($timestamp >= $maybegin) && ($timestamp <= $mayend)){

echo '<li>';
echo $path . ' ' . $link_title;
echo '</li>';

} else {

if (($timestamp >= $aprilbegin) && ($timestamp <= $aprilend)){

echo '<li>';
echo $path . ' ' . $link_title;
echo '</li>';

}
}
}
}
}
```

**Edit 6/21/18**

This works and outputs the correct markup for a jQuery accordian:

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {

    $timestamp = filemtime($path);

    $files[date('F', $timestamp)][$path] = $timestamp;

}

arsort($files); 

        echo '<div class="accordion">';

        foreach ($files as $month => $paths) {

            krsort($paths);

        echo '<h6>' . $month . '</h6><div><ul>';

        foreach ($paths as $path => $timestamp) {

        echo '<li>' . $path . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul></div>';

    }
        echo '</div>';
```

Comment: If you want `$link_title` to be different for each file, you need to set it *inside* the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Ah, that worked. Thanks. But do I need a foreach loop for each month to sort by $timestamp within each month?

Comment: They're already sorted by timestamp, aren't they? Why would you need to sort them again for each month?

Comment: i'm trying to be sure they are grouped by month so I can do the next step, which is add html markup for a jQuery accordian for each month.

Comment: Ah. Well you don't need to sort them, since that's already done. You do need a loop that goes through the months so you can group them. I'll add an example as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your end-goal is to group the filenames by month, you need a loop to show you only the entries from the `$files` array that match a particular month:

```
$months = array(
    '2018-07',
    '2018-06',
    '2018-05',
    '2018-04'
);

foreach ($months as $month) {
    // just some example markup
    echo '<p>' . $month . '</p>';

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($files as $path => $timestamp) {
        if (date('Y-m', $timestamp) == $month) {
            echo '<li>' . $path . '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

If you already know that you're not going to use your `$files` array for anything else, another option might be to simply group the files while processing the `glob` results:

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {
    $timestamp = filemtime($path);

    $files[date('Y-m', $timestamp)][$path] = $timestamp;
}
```

Since it's now a nested array, you can't simply `arsort()` the whole thing. But you can delay that until you want to loop over the file list to generate the desired HTML output:

```
// first sort the whole thing by keys (year + month), so that the months are sorted:
krsort($files);

foreach ($files as $month => $paths) {
    // now sort the paths by their timestamps
    arsort($paths);

    // and output whatever markup you want
    echo '<p>' . $month . '</p>';

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($paths as $path => $timestamp) {
        echo '<li>' . $path . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

**EDIT AFTER THE UPDATED QUESTION**

You seem to be misunderstanding a basic concept of defining variables in loops.

You have two separate loops in your code: one that processes the result of `glob()` and one that turns the result of that processing into markup for your jQuery accordion.

By defining `$monthname` in the *first* loop, it will maintain its last value when processing the `glob()` result is finished.

You want to *use* `$monthname` in the *second* loop, but you're not setting it there. Therefore, it will **always** be the same value: the last value it was when processing the `glob()` result. Instead, you should define `$monthname` where you want to use it.

> Sidenote: I used `date('Y-m')` in my answer as an example, since I didn't know what you were going to display. If you always want to display the date as `date('F')`, you can simply use that for the array key instead. Then there's no need to keep track of a separate `$monthname` variable and you can simply output the `$month` value in the second loop. However, this *might* not be what you want, if you have files in there that have been modified in the same month but in different years.

As for the specific warnings you're seeing, they are caused by the fact that you're storing each file into the `$files` array twice now:

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $path) {
    if($path == 'index.php') {
    continue;
    }  // removes all files names index.php

/**** HERE: ****/
    $files[$path] = filemtime($path);

    $timestamp = filemtime ($path);
    // needed to define $timestamp

/**** AND HERE: ****/
    $files[date('Y-m', $timestamp)][$path] = $timestamp;

    $monthname = (date('F', $timestamp));
    // display month full name instead of month numeral
}
```

This means that the `$files` array looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [/var/www/file.php] => 1529239095
    [2018-06] => Array
        (
            [/var/www/file.php] => 1529239095
        )

)
```

Because you still have that first assignment in there, you now occasionally try to sort (which you copy/pasted incorrectly, it should be an `arsort()` instead of `krsort()`) a timestamp (integer) instead of an array of `path => timestamp` entries. You should remove that first assignment.

Comment: Thanks! Your second example seems to be the best; I've been trying it out, and I added some markup and am getting a few php errors. See my updated question.

Comment: thanks! I got it to work. I will post the working code.

Comment: Thanks again. I changed my overall idea from sorting by filemtime to sorting by a date in the file name, i.e yyyy-mm-dd-file-name.php, as filemtime turned out to be a problem. I was able to get the month from the file date with `$files[substr($path, 5, 2 )][$path] = $path;` and use that as a key to sort by. But if I want to also sort all by year, what's a good way to do that? Add another key for the year to the array and use krsort to first sort by year for a separate accordian for each year?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Why not use `substr($path, 0, 7)` to include the year in the array index?

Comment: I was thinking of a multidimensional array with the year and month; would that be efficient? Or use an if statement before the arsort to determine which year and then use two accordion markup loops? Maybe it's about equal for the efficiency of each.

Comment: Meh, there's this trap called "premature optimization". Efficiency doesn't really come into play until your array contains thousands of entries or you need to loop through it dozens or hundreds of times. A multidimensional array should work fine.