# How can I add part of each file name to an array generated by glob?

Tags: php, arrays

PHP beginner here; this is a farily basic question and I can't find a simple explanation or example on SE after searching.

*Edited due to issues pointed out by barmar.*

I have a directory of lots of files, i.e.

```
2018-03-21-file-name.php
2018-07-04-file-name-too.php
2018-05-30-another-file-name.php
2018-07-04-file-too.php
... more
```

The strings of numbers in the file names are dates in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Some files may have the same date.

I'm using glob to create an array of those files

`$files = (glob("*.php"));`

and     `var_dump` shows me the results:

```
[0]=> string(18) "2018-03-21-file-name.php"
[1]=> string(22) "2018-07-04-file-name-too.php"
[2]=> string(25) "2018-05-30-another-file-name.php"
... more
```

The files are naturally sorted by glob in numerical order; but I want to sort the files by month. But in order to do that, I think I need to extract the month number from each file name and insert it in the `$files` array for each corresponding file name.

So how do I get the month number from each file and add it to the array so I can sort the files into groups of months?

This is my earlier question [Glob files and sort by filemtime and into months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888959/glob-files-and-sort-by-filemtime-and-into-months) where I sorted by month and date by file modification date into markup for a jQuery accordion, but I found that using `filemtime` has problems, so I need to change to sorting by a date in the actual file name.

I.e.,

```
$files = (glob("*.php"));

krsort($files);

foreach ...
```

Comment: What if you have two dates in the same month? You can't have duplicate keys, so `krsort()` would not work.

Comment: Can you fix your file naming scheme? Using `yyyy-mm-dd` makes them sort by date automatically.

Comment: @Barmar ah, good point about duplicate keys; I didn't think of that; I will have files with the same date. I can change to `yyyy-mm-dd`, and that will help. This is my earlier question where I found issues with sorting by `filemtime` so I want to change to a date in the file name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888959/glob-files-and-sort-by-filemtime-and-into-months So how should I sort with files with the same date?

Comment: If you change the filename to use `yyyy-mm-dd` you can just sort by the filename. Files with the same date will be sorted by the rest of the name.

Comment: Ok, thanks. There's a reason you have a 386K rep. Then how would I break up the file list into months to be able to use html markup to separate the months? Still using one of the posted answers?

Comment: Are you interested in month only or year/month?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to do it is to define your own sort function and use `usort()` like this:

```
$glob = ['03-05-18-file-name.php',
'30-11-18-file-name-too.php',
'21-08-18-another-file-name.php'];

function cmp($a, $b)
{ 
    $month_a = substr($a,3,2);
    $month_b = substr($b,3,2);

    if ($month_a == $month_b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($month_a < $month_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($glob, "cmp");

print_r($glob);
```

Note that all months are grouped together. If you want years or days-of-month separated, you will need to modify the `cmp` function.

Comment: If you are on PHP7 you can use the spaceship operator and do `return substr($a,3,2) <=> substr($b,3,2);` instead.

Comment: @KodosJohnson  Thanks, I am on php7.

Comment: @mankowitz thanks, that looks interesting. I guess my question is incomplete, re: the output, and I tried to output the list of filenames in a foreach loop, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

It uses a regular expression to take the date out of the filename and use it as the key or index for the array **$ordered**.  Then **krsort** is called.

```
$files = ['03-05-18-file-name.php','30-11-18-file-name-too.php','21-08-18-anothe
r-file-name.php'];

$ordered = [];
foreach ($files as $f) {
    $dateKey = preg_replace('/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+).*$/','$3$2$1',$f);
    $ordered[$dateKey] = $f;
}
krsort($ordered);
var_dump($files,$ordered);

foreach ($ordered as $o) {
    echo $o.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. But I guess my question is incomplete, re: the output, and I tried to output the list of filenames in a foreach loop, but no luck.

Comment: **krsort** sorts the array you pass into it, so the foreach loop runs on the sorted array

Comment: @user218349 thanks, this works. I eventually need to sort by year, but I wanted to figure out how to sort by months first. A new issue has appeared, pointed out by barmar, that if I have files with the same date - which I will - there will be the same key used by multiple objects in the array. So I'm thinking now I will change the file name system to yyyy-mm-dd-filename.php and glob will automatically sort by date. So then I simply need to arrange the result by month, maybe with a if then loop, rather than a sort an array with a key. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes - changing the file name is the best solution. You can include the time in the file name as well.

Comment: True, I could include the time, but I don't want that to show up in the URL for each page.

Comment: Changing the preg_replace to `/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/` works for the yyyy-mm-dd date format of the file names